# Expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program that will generate labor times based on labor rate, and I'm running into the `Expected unqualified-id before '{' token` error.

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double S516 = 5.5; // 516-70 Alloy welds at 5.5 inches per minute
double A304 = 4.3; // A304 Steel welds at 4.3 inches per minute
double x; // This value is a placeholder for total linear inches to be welded

int main()

{
    cout << "Please enter the total number of inches to be welded:\n ";
    cin >> x;
}
    {
        if S516, then multiplies[(S516 * x *1.1 / 60];
        else if A304, then multiplies[(A304 * x * 1.1 / 60];
    }
```

Am I even on the right track for all of this?

Comment: The error is throwing on line 14 of my program, according to CodeBlocks

Comment: And I think you'd find that if you have code in braces outside of a function, that is the error your compiler gives. I know it's not saying "you have code outside the function `main`", but that's because the compiler isn't quite sure what you are doing [it also looks like your code won't compile AFTER fixing that either, but it's definitely necessary to fix the "code outside main"]

Comment: That's nowhere near valid C++. What possessed you to write those last few lines like that?!

Comment: what you think your program does, line by line? there are syntax errors everywhere! Answer the question  and i will be able to help you

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to teach myself from the ground up. I don't even know what including iostream does, except that it's pretty much necessary, same with namespace. The doubles are calling S516 and A304 specific numbers so I won't have to type them in again, and refer back to those specific decimals. I don't know what int main does, but I'm told it's necessary. The cout and cin lines are meant to assign X to a user specified input, and the last two are meant to spit out a mathematical equation.

Comment: @TRP the last 2 lines are pseudocode. It means a human can understand them, but a compiler can't, because a compiler expects that you strictly follow the syntax. Can you write, in plain English, what you want those 2 lines to do? For example: `if S516` isn't clear. Do you mean "If the value x inserted by the user is equal to S516, then calculate this"? Then you must know that it isn't obvious (to the compiler at least) that you are talking about `x`, you must say it explicitly like `if (x == S516)`. And what should be done with the result? Print it, store it into a variable...?

Comment: Those last two lines, in an ideal world, are meant to take the pre-stored value if it's A304 being welded, multiplied by the total number of inches to be welded on the job and by 1.1 for a 10% "fudge factor," then divide by 60 to convert minutes to hours taken to weld that much material at that material's welding rate. The idea is for the shop to give me a list of materials, what their welding rates are, and I come up with a program that tells them how many hours a given job will take. The approach I want to take is to use if/then style, since there won't be that many variables to account for.

Comment: @TRP Ok, but let's suppose the user enters `10`. How does the program know that material S516 is being used, and therefore the calculation must be `5.5 * 10 *1.1 / 60`? Or, how does the program know it's A304? I would say the user must tell the program, therefore you need one more variable for the material choice, and one more `cin` to read that variable. And then, let'say it is done: what should the program do? The result with S516 and x = 10 is 1.00833333, and then? Should the program print it with a `cout`? Should this value be stored in another variable, so that it can be used again?

Comment: That result is correct, and it should tell the end user that it will take right about an hour to weld 10 inches, which would be the double x callout at the very top. It should then terminate upon user request. How will it do that, I literally do not know. I've been trying to pull knowledge from every source to figure out how to make this work, because I have trouble with learning conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here:

In your main function, you'll want the if/else-if statement within the same curly brackets as the cout/cin.

The following two lines are not valid C++ code:

```
if S516, then multiplies [(S516 * x *1.1 / 60];
else if A304, then multiplies [(A304 * x * 1.1 / 60];
```

Instead try:

```
double answer = 0.0;
if (x==S516){
    answer = (S516 * x * 1.1 / 60);
}
else if (x==A304){
    answer = (A304 * x * 1.1 / 60);
}
```

I don't know what your arithmetic is doing, so I left it alone, but I feel like that is not exactly what you wanted to compute. But I'll leave that part to you.

Additionally as a matter of preference on most peoples parts, try to avoid using global variables. For "double x;" I would move that into main.

It seems like you might be new to programming/C++ and are jumping the gun. You should start with basic tutorials.

Use the other answer for the full solution.

Comment: there is no need to return 0 in main, if the final return is omitted 0 will be returned by default (that's only valid for `main`)

Comment: You have false statements and syntax errors in this answer :(

Comment: Also I added the semicolon that I forgot. Alert me of other syntax errors

Comment: That code up top is throwing two errors, expected unqualified id before if and else. Is there actually a good tutorial for this stuff? I've tried four different tutorials, and can't make heads or tails of any of them.

Comment: @AndrewCorsini I'm afraid the OP doesn't understand the error "expected unqualified id", he doesn't realise he is writing code outside of main (and of everything). I know a lot of people here at SO are against giving complete, ready-to-use code, but I think a snippet won't really help him. You have explained what he should do, but in this case I would give him the full code. I think it would be a lot clearer.

Comment: How am I writing code outside of something? There's {} brackets around everything past int main, aren't there?

Comment: I added a potential untested solution. Take a look at what I did and compare to yours and see if you can spot the differences.

Comment: @AndrewCorsini: argh, I hadn't seen you had updated your answer. I have posted mine now :-(. Anyway, if you check the comments to the question, you'll see `if(x == A304)` is not what he meant. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double S516 = 5.5; // 516-70 Alloy welds at 5.5 inches per minute
double A304 = 4.3; // A304 Steel welds at 4.3 inches per minute


enum material {
    material_S516 = 1,
    material_A304 = 2
};

int main()
{
    double x; // This value is a placeholder for total linear inches to be welded
    cout << "Please enter the total number of inches to be welded:" << endl;
    cin >> x;

    int material_to_weld;
    cout << "Please indicate the material you have to weld (enter 1 for S516 or 2 for A304):" << endl;
    cin >> material_to_weld;

    double time_to_weld, corrected_time_to_weld;
    if (material_to_weld == material_S516) {
        time_to_weld = S516 * x * 1.1 / 60;
        corrected_time_to_weld = x * 1.1 / S516 / 60;
    } else if (material_to_weld == material_A304) {
        time_to_weld = A304 * x * 1.1 / 60;
        corrected_time_to_weld = x * 1.1 / A304 / 60;
    } else {
        cout << "Invalid material! Please choose either 1 or 2!" << endl;
        return(1);
    }

    cout << "With the original formula, welding " << x << " inches of this material will take " << time_to_weld << " hours." << endl;
    cout << "With the corrected formula, welding " << x << " inches of this material will take " << corrected_time_to_weld << " hours." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is not really how I would write it, but I tried to keep it simple. One thing you should really notice is that your formula looks wrong - the time required to weld increases with the speed. Time = space / speed, so I think you want to use `x * 1.1 / S516 / 60`. This way if the speed increases the time decreases, as expected. But anyway I have kept both calculations.

As you can see, all the code is inside the `main()` function. In your code it was, yes, inside braces, but those braces had no meaning, and they were outside of `main()`. The error you got was cryptic, but that's what it meant.

Some more remarks:

- It's `#include`, not `include`!
- Your S516 and A304 variables are declared as global variables, because they are outside of `main()`. I left them there, but you could actually move them into `main()`. In this case there's no practical difference, but it's a good practice to use global variables only when you **really** need them (which can happen, but very seldom).
- As I told you in some comments, you need one more variable for the choice of the material, and the corresponding `cout` and `cin`. Please note that when you read input from the user you should normally validate it, that is, check that it's valid. Here, for example, the accepted values are `1` and `2`, and if the user enters 3 the program will display "Invalid material! Please choose either 1 or 2!" and terminate. Another approach could be to insert this into a loop, that keeps asking the user to choose either 1 or 2, and the loop stops only after the user has provided valid input
- I have used an `enum` for the material. Enums are normally safer than ints, but I haven't used it in a really good way. Still, it's probably a lot of stuff for you to study, and I've decided to keep it simple, so I have used it like this.

I hope this can help you.